# uniform initialization and std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, uniform-initialization

I'm learning C++ and I got to the point where I'm reading about list initialization. 
After a bit of confusion,due to syntax overlapping, I understood that uniform initialization and list initialization are indeed two different (albeit as I just said overlapping) new features of C++11.
So,before I ask my question I would like to recap,and please correct me if I'm geting something wrong (before that something becomes a misconception about this topic..)

as far as built-in types are concerned,the syntax for initializing them is as follows (I'm assuming int for readability):

```
// defines a default initialized int
int a;
// defines a value initialized int (binary zeroes)
int a{};

// equivalent definitions,define an int variable of value 10:
int a=10;
int a(10);
int a{10};
int a={10};

// equivalent definitions,define a temporary int variable of value 10:
int(10);
int{10};

// equivalent definitions,define a temporary int variable that is value initialized to 0:
int();
int{};
```

now to the interesting part, using the uniform initialization for aggregate types (arrays and aggregate structs).
Until C++11 I could initialize arays and aggregate classes with a list initializer:

```
int array[]={1,2,3};

struct aggregate {
  int a;
  double b;
};

aggregate a={1,2.3};
```

now,I know that the new standard allows me to use the new syntax for the uniform initialization:

```
int array[]{1,2,3};
aggregate a{1,2,3};
```

this may come in handy for using in constructor's member initialization lists.

and now,to the class types.
If a class doesn't define a initializers_list constructor:

```
// equivalent definitions,define a class_type variable,default initialized:
class_type name;
class_type name{};

// equivalent definitions,define a class_type variable,using the appropriate constructor:
class_type name(*args*);
class_type name{*args*};
class_type name={*args*};

// defines a class_type variable and calls copy-constructor (allows implicit conversion to class_type if converting constructor is non-explicit)
class_type name=name2;      

// equivalent definitions,define a temporary class_type object,default initialized
class_type();
class_type{};

// equivalent definitions,define a temporary class_type object,initialized by the appropriate constructor
class_type(*args*);
class_type{*args*};
```

I know that when a class defines a class_type::class_type(const std::initializer_list&) constructor, it takes precedence over other constructors (unless it's an empty list and then the default constructor takes precedence).

Now, my question is:

what does the `=` change when I use it with a braced list? The only difference I could think of is whether the init list constructor is explicit or not.Is

```
class_type name{*args*};
class_type name={*args*};
```

the same as

```
class_type name({*args*});
class_type name=class_type(std::initializer_list({*args*}));
```

and so copy initialization implicit conversion are involved? is it the only difference?

please, correct me if I'm saying something blaringly wrong!

Comment: `class_type name;` default initialized vs `class_type name{};` value-initialized. it is not the same.

Comment: A value-initialized `int` always has the value 0, even if you are on a crazy architecture where the value 0 is not all-bits-zero. Both `class_type()` and `class_type{}` are value-initialization assuming that the class isn't an aggregate.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, isn't it the same for class types? the default constructor is always called

Comment: They are different if the default constructor is not user-provided.